# Why is ActiveResource returning Arrays of Hashes instead of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I've just started building an api and application that consumes from the api using ActiveResource. I'll get into specifics with an edit, but my initial problem is this:

I have a controller that does Resource.find(resource.id), that will return an object, and if I include on the api side, the included association are also easily worked with objects. To pull a more customized collection the application goes to a custom action on the api, this will return an Array of Hashes that isn't as easily worked with(e.g. with link_to).

First question: why?

As stated I'll fill in more if necessary (it gets more complicated from my perspective, maybe not so from a professional/expert perspective so I'll hold off for now). I'm hoping someone can give an explanation allowing me more control over ActiveResource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/CustomMethods.html

the custom resource used .get, so:

"
Note: the objects returned from this method are not automatically converted into ActiveResource::Base instances - they are ordinary Hashes. If you are expecting ActiveResource::Base instances, use the find class method with the :from option.
"

So, trying another way....

Comment: ....which is learning to use .find more effectively than I was able to previously